# Redirect rule doesn't contain all the query parameters

Tags: rules

I`ve set up a Rule to redirect a user after log in. 
The Rule works redirecting the user to the URL specified, but it doesn't contain all the query parameters after "?".

This is the URL value:

*user/login?destination=node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]&cs1=[entity-fetched-household:0:hash]&cid2=[account:civicrm-contact:contact-id]&cs2=[account:civicrm-contact:hash]*

But the user is redirected to the following one:

*user/login?destination=node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]*

just containing the first query parameter cid1.

I've checked the other parameters, cs1, cid2, cs2, contain the correct values.

This is the export of the Rule:

```
{ "rules_add_parameters_to_url_related_to_contact_id" : {

"LABEL" : "Add parameters to url related to contact id",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "path" ],
"ON" : { "user_login" : [] },
"DO" : [
  { "entity_query" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "civicrm_contact",
        "property" : "display_name",
        "value" : [ "account:civicrm-contact:household-name" ],
        "limit" : "1"
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_fetched" : { "entity_fetched_household" : "Fetched entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "redirect" : { "url" : "user\/login?destination=node\/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]\u0026cs1=[entity-fetched-household:0:hash]\u0026cid2=[account:civicrm-contact:contact-id]\u0026cs2=[account:civicrm-contact:hash]" } },
]
  }
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way drupal_parse_url() parses your URL. If you think this is wrong, you can escape your & characters and file an issue in the core Drupal issue queue.

```
$ drush php-eval 'print_r(drupal_parse_url("user/login?destination=node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]&cs1=[entity-fetched-household:0:hash]&cid2=[account:civicrm-contact:contact-id]&cs2=[account:civicrm-contact:hash]"));'
Array
(
    [path] => user/login
    [query] => Array
        (
            [destination] => node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]
            [cs1] => [entity-fetched-household:0:hash]
            [cid2] => [account:civicrm-contact:contact-id]
            [cs2] => [account:civicrm-contact:hash]
        )

    [fragment] => 
)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: would I need to implement a hook to change the behavior of the function drupal_parse_url()? At the moment I have never worked to extend or alter the core behavior of Drupal. Could you quickly guide me where I should implement this change in the Drupal core functionality?

Comment: No hook needed. drupal_parse_url() sees your URL as user/login followed by ? followed by a bunch of key=value pairs separated by &. So it's parsing destination= , cs1=, cid2=, cs2=. But that's not what you intended - you intended those key=value pairs to be part of the destination.  How is drupal_parse_url() supposed to know that? I would have to look at the RFC to be sure, but I think drupal_parse_url() is doing the correct thing here. The way you can force it to do what you want is to escape the & symbols so drupal_parse_url() doesn't see them as &. To do this, simply replace them with %2c.

Comment: ````$ drush php-eval 'print_r(drupal_parse_url("user/login?destination=node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id]%2ccs1=[entity-fetched-household:0:hash]%2ccid2=[account:civicrm-contact:contact-id]%2ccs2=[account:civicrm-contact:hash]"));'
Array
(
    [path] => user/login
    [query] => Array
        (
            [destination] => node/4?cid1=[entity-fetched-household:0:contact-id],cs1=[entity-fetched-household:0:hash],cid2=[account:civicrm-contact:contact-id],cs2=[account:civicrm-contact:hash]
        )

    [fragment] => 
)
````